# My update manager is not working

Tags: 12.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

An error occurred, please run package manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in terminal to see what is wrong.

The error message was:

```
'unknown error:'<type 'exceptions.system Error '>' ('E:The package tty-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.' this usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies
```

Answer (score 2):

Your system's dependencies are broken. Fix it by just type following command in terminal. open terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+t or search **Terminal** in dash.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
```